# Как зафиксировать label когда происходит onchange Input'a?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, css-animation

На код не ругайтесь, на скорую руку набросал.
Собственно нужно чтобы когда в поле ввели текст плейсхолдер блокировался , а не возвращался в инпут. помогите пожалуйста. https://jsfiddle.net/h7jmLuyz/

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputName" required>
    <label for="inputName" class=" name-placeholder"><span class="placeholder">Имя</span></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" required>
    <label for="inputName" class=" phone-placeholder"><span class="placeholder">Телефон</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: и как вы хотите без js проверить количество введенных символов в поле?

Comment: Это всё без js делается

Comment: @Doofy буду очень признателен если поможете

Comment: @DoneBass щя поколдую

Comment: @Doofy максимум что можно сделать, это проверять на валидность псевдо-классом `:invalid`. Но это все фигня на постном масле. А на `:empty` поля не проверяются

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Поможете с решением на js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 32px;
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  
  width: 256px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
  
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.input + span:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(name);
  left: 9px;
  top: -2px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.input:valid + span:before {
  margin-top: -32px;
  transition: .2s ease;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<label><input class='input' type='text' required><span name='Имя'></span></label>
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, нужно скрыть placeholder при заполненом поле. Что касается стилей, лучше всегда обходиться без JS

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли, переделал немного Ваш код под себя.
Нужно было чтобы не скрывался а фиксировался над инпутом.